# Excel countif formula two conditions

Tags: excel, countif

I am having difficulties with the countif formula, because I need to count if a certain sheet has values that start with the number "2" but only if its length is equal to "9".

[image]

```
=(COUNTIFS(sheet2_2019!A:A;"2*";sheet2_2019!A:A;SUMPRODUCT(N(LEN(sheet_2019!A:A)=9))))
```

The first part is easy, to see if the cell starts with "2" but the length I not figuring out how to do it.

Do you know how can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe: "2????????"

Comment: @JvdV that won't work if the data is actually numbers though and not text. I can't tell from the screenshot though.

Comment: @BigBen I believe the OP has the values stored as text, by the fact that they stated: `The first part is easy, to see if the cell starts with "2"`  and is using `COUNTIFS(sheet2_2019!A:A;"2*"` already

Comment: @JvdV please put that as an answer, because in this case, I believe it to be the best.

Comment: @ScottCraner - A2 and A3 are right-aligned so I wasn't sure. A5 looks left aligned.

Comment: @ScottCraner, I'm on the phone so I threw down a very bare answer.

Comment: OP: can you clarify whether you have values stored as text or as true numbers? I'm not able to tell from your screenshot.

Comment: They are stored as text, they are extracted from a csv file

Comment: I would advise against that - Excel can import as numbers. But if they must be text, then see @JvdV's answer as it is the best.

Comment: Yes, for what I can see the JvdV's  is working. I known that is not the best way, but it is an old excel template and for the time being I cannot change it. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the asterisks, you could apply the question mark wildcard as a placeholder for any character making up a string of nine in total.: `2????????`

```
=COUNTIFS(sheet2_2019!A:A,"2????????")
```

Comment: Apparently this is working, I will test it in more detail. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with *numbers*, perhaps like this:

```
=COUNTIFS(sheet2_2019!A:A;">="&2*10^8;sheet2_2019!A:A;"<"&3*10^8)
```

This is based on the assumption that the underlying data is true numbers, and not values stored as text.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use COUNTIFS and use `LEN()`.  When needing to manipulate the data one will need to use an array type formula like SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEFT(sheet2_2019!A2:A4)="2")*(LEN(sheet2_2019!A2:A4)=9))
```

Being an array like formula, for best performance one must use the data range and not full column references.